# How do I insert backslash?

Tags: ruby, regex, special-characters

I have string like `file name`. I want to output like `file\ name`. I have tried following.

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :060 > s.gsub(/\s/,"\ ")  
 => "file name"   
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :074 > s.gsub(" ","\\")  
 => "file\\name"
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want

```
s.gsub(" ","\\ ")
=> "file\\ name"
```

This *is* a single backslash character, but its representation needs a double backslash to differentiate it from an actual escape sequence like `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use 'single quoted strings'. They are not escaped in ruby.

Comment: ... except for some special characters like backslash.

Comment: @undur_gongor True story. Didn't know that!